# ClassNotFoundException loading Oracle drivers with Jetty/Gradle

Tags: oracle, jetty, gradle

I am running up against a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` exception when trying to run Jetty through Gradle and am running out of ideas.  The jetty config in gradle points to an env file:

`[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.jettyEnvXml = file('../resources/jetty/jetty-env.xml')`

and within that file is JNDI config:

```
<New id="OracleDS" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
  <Arg>java:comp/env/OracleDS</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
      ...
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

I've been trying adding an extraClasspath to that file, setting the jetty.home system property, and adding dependencies to the jar (to the webapp and also to the buildscript). I've also tried the simpler `OracleDataSource` class. Any concrete advice would be enormously helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the library file to the webapp as a standard dependency did the trick.

`providedRuntime files("$projectDir/../lib/ojdbc14.jar")`

I was unfortunately embarking down the more app server influenced approach.  Unfortunately none of the options provided much feedback, so grepping through the --debug output showed that that solution led to the library being consistently loaded.

Comment: I don't think there is a fundamentally better way (in which ways could it be better?), except that you should use `providedRuntime` unless you want the driver to end up in the War. Not sure what you mean by "other than just adding it to a new configuration".

Comment: Yes, since then I've added it to a new configuration. And will update the answer accordingly.  The better solutions question was primarily a matter of "I'm still working out how to use Gradle effectively and not sure whether there is a problem/bad practice with this approach that I don't see" and not because I actually have any problem with it or seek improvement for it. Your being a trusted source answers my concerns.  (As an aside I am proselytizing Spock and Gradle at work and am gaining converts).

Comment: I don't think that nesting `dependencies` under `configurations` gives anything over having the `dependencies` block on the top level. In other words, the `configurations { jetty { } }` part isn't serving any purpose. It's adding a new configuration without doing anything with it. This leads to the question what the `dependsOn` line is doing.

Comment: I stole that from somewhere and it seemed to fit where I thought I would need to go: but I didn't end up needing it and the thought may have been wrong anyway.  I also misread your first comment (got lost on the line break).  I was preparing for a need for more configuration differences with the Jetty environment to make up for missing AS stuff, but little of that entered the gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using the 'additionalRuntimeJars' property:

```
jettyRun {
    additionalRuntimeJars = configurations.myJettyRuntime // for oracle classes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Oracle dependency into the Jetty plugin configuration